# Does system properties have size limit?

Tags: unix, hp-ux, system-properties

I am using HP-Unix server. One of system property has a very long string as its value. We notice that the value of the system property gets corrupted. While the other system properties are in-tact.
I am wondering, if there is any size limitation for the system properties in HP-Unix.

Thanks in Advance

Vinod

Comment: Acceptable values are defined on a property by property basis. What is the property?

Comment: It's an user defined property not any existing property

Comment: what is a "property" where is the user defining it?